# How to do things to a element on mouseenter?

Tags: javascript, php, mouseenter

how to execute something on mouse enter? like show in the code down below.

```
for(x=1; isset($_COOKIE["link$x"]); $x++)
    echo <div id="'.$x.'" OnMouseEnter="myfunction('.$x.')">
}
```

and then in javascript

```
function myfunction(which){
    // doing stuff on id with "which"
}
```

Comment: sorry for confusing title, i mean mouseenter like the jQuery mouseenter http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/

Comment: Wait, do you want to call a function, or change a style?

Comment: Did any of the answers work?

Answer (score 1):

`onmouseenter` is specific to IE, so use `onmouseover`:

```
myElement.onmouseover = function()
{
    document.getElementById(which).style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

yes, it's as simple as that... notice I changed `red` to `'red'`, because I don't think you've defined **red.**  This is how to do it in Javascript, though it would be *much* simpler to do it in CSS with `:hover`, but you're asking for Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to apply a style on mouseover, you don't need JavaScript. The CSS `:hover` pseudo-selector should work fine:

```css
#elementId {
  background: white;
}

#elementId:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: `:hover` doesn't seem to be the same as `mouseenter`.

Comment: I tried this first, but then i realize i needed to change another element that i don't hover, the javascript is simplified badly, i'll edit it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to go that far...

you can do this simply and easily using a :hover pseudo class.

in your css create two rules

```
.myHoverDiv
{
  /* any styles you need here that show when not hovered over */
}

.myHoverDiv:hover
{
  /* any styles here that should change when the mouse hovers over it */
  background-color: red;
}
```

then on your tag use

```
<div class="myHoverDiv"> ... div inner contents here ... </div>
```

your div's style will change as expected when the mouse is hovered over it

Answer (score 1):

As kumar_v asked too, i guess you shoud use "OnMouseOver" instead of "OnMouseEnter" to get a "hover"-effect.

So your PHP-code should be like that:

```
for($x=1; isset($_COOKIE["link$x"]); $x++) {
    echo '<div id="'.$x.'" OnMouseOver="myfunction('.$x.')">test</div>';
}
```

and Javascript:

```
function myfunction(which){
    document.getElementById(which).style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Comment: This works very good, but when i move my mouse outside i want it to get back like it was before, without the red background

Comment: Then you also have to write something like that into your <div>-element: `OnMouseOut="myfunction_out('.$x.')"` and the function `myfunction_out(which) { document.getElementById(which).style.backgroundColor = ""; }` or a default color of your choice

Answer (score 1):

better you handle your javascript in one block and I suggest you to make a handler to do that for you, if you use common javascript library such as [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and [mouseover](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), that becomes super easier to handle and debug, remember add jQuery library to head of page.

server-side:

```
echo '<div id="handler_id">';
for(x=1; isset($_COOKIE["link$x"]); $x++)
    echo <div id="'.$x.'">
}
echo '</div>';
```

client-side, this part is in within `<script />` tag or in separated js file:

```
(function(window, $) {
var window.handler = handler = {
    init: function() {
        $('#handler_id > div').mouseover(function(){
            console.log("mouse is over", this);
        });
    }
}
$(function(){ handler.init(); });
})(window, jQuery)
```